# Cannot read value of property after ajax request

Tags: ajax, reactjs, typescript, axios

My code looks like this:

```
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        list: [],
    };
}

public componentWillMount() {
    this.getData();
}

public getData = () => {   
        axios.get(someURL)
        .then( (response) => {
            this.setState({list: response.data.arrivals});
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            console.log("FAILED", error);
        });
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
    const {list}: any = this.state;
    const data: IScheduler = list;

    console.log("TEST");

    console.log(data); //cannot get data here

    console.log("TEST");

    return (
        <div className="main-page-container">
            <ArrivalsTable data={data}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My problem is that I am unable to read my data.

```
 console.log(data);
```

gives me back an array:

```
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

and

```
 console.log(data.generatedDate);
```

gives:

```
 undefined
```

A sample of my data (modified):

```
{
   "arrivals": [
       {
          "generatedDate": "03.12.2017"
       }
        ...
    ]
}
```

I was wondering how to fix that. Can anyone help?

(Tried to fix that, but still I cannot get data in render() )

Is there any other way to fetch data from URL and put them into property?

Comment: Try adding a `console.log` into your response. Are you seeing data come back in the `.then()`?

Comment: @Stuart Casarotto, Yes

Comment: what do you get when you do `console.log(response);` inside the `.then` method?

Comment: I get a response with status 200 and an array with my data.

Comment: Try `console.log(list)` in your `render()`?

Comment: Didn't work. An array with length 0..

Answer (score 0):

getData should be as as below

```
axios.get(someURL)
    .then((response) => {
        this.setState({list: response.data.arrivals});
    })
    .catch( (error) => {
        console.log("FAILED", error);
    });
}
```

Note the `this.setState({list: response.data.arrivals});` section.

Comment: Oh. You're right! Maybe do you know why I cannot reach data in render() ?

Comment: can you post your complete render() method?

Comment: modify const {list}: any = this.state; as const {list}: any = this.state.list; in the render() method

Comment: I got an error: Property 'list' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'

Comment: My bad. It should be const list: any = this.state.list; If that doesn't work add console.log(this.state) at the top of the render() method and see what's inside state object

Comment: The same error as above. There is a: 'list: Array(0)' inside state object. It has an empty 'list: []' and '__proto__: Object'.